# How to fix "exception during rendering Index 2; Size 2" error in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I've been working on designing my app for different screen resolutions. I've been adding different value folders, different styles, and everything's been fine. I've updated a few graphics by adding high-res versions in -hdpi and -xhdpi folders.

All of a sudden, Eclipse will not render any UIs of mdpi. I get rendering exception error Index 2; Size 2.

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Edit: Turns out it was a random bug. To fix, I selected a style in the .xml, cut it, pasted it back and saved. Problem went away.

Comment: Please post the constructors for the custom view(s) you are using.

Comment: Turns out it was a stupid bug. Selected a style in the .xml, cut it, pasted it back, saved - fixed.